# Api call from angular 2 not working at first time

Tags: angular2-services

Hi I am very new in angular, I am calling an API from angular service but at first hit, it directly goes to catch and in subscribe, data is coming like the Unexpected end of input , but after few minutes it is hitting the API and extractData method is also getting hit with specific successful json:
service:

```
  getUsers(userName: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    debugger;
    return this._http.get("http://localhost:51802/Login?userName=" + userName + "&password=" + password)
        .map((this.extractData))
        .catch(this._errorHandler);

}

  private extractData(res: Response) {
        return res.text() ? res.json() : {};
    }
    _errorHandler(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error || "Server Error");
    }
```

component:

```
 public loginUsers(loginId: string, password: string) {
        console.log(this.loginForm);
        if (this.loginForm.valid) {
            this._loginService.getUsers(loginId, password).subscribe(data => this.users = data);
           // this.users = this._loginService.getUsers(body);
            console.log('form submitted');
           // this.router.navigateByUrl('index');
        } else {
            this.validateAllFormFields(this.loginForm);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:51802/api/acc/Login?userName=' + userName + '&password=' + password)
```

Comment: @A.Sakeer url is working now but it is hitting after few minutes not at very first time